# What is the name of the structure and the components of such words?

Tags: terminology

In English as in many language, there are things which their names are made of two words or nouns, such as: shower-stall, toilet-room, washing-machines, and so on. My question is what is the name of the first component and the second component? (As far as I know the second component only can become plural)

Comment: Those are called compound nouns. But washing machine does not need a hyphen. Some compound nouns are simply two words. I have never heard of toilet room.

Answer (score 2):

Things which their names are made of two words are called: **compound words**.

Then there are "open compound words" and "closed compound words" as follow:

> ***open compound words***, such as living-room, coffee-mug.
>
> ***closed compound words***, such as bookstore, notebook.

Source: [compound words](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/open-and-closed-compound-words/).